# reading very large xml file and extracting nodes

Tags: xml, perl

i am processing a very large xml file (over 15 G ) and i think my code can be improved.
here is the code :

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $fname=$ARGV[0] ||  die 'input xml is required';
my $xsd1 = $ARGV[1] || die 'input xsd is required';

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => "$fname",Schema => "$xsd1" )
     or die "cannot read $fname\n";
while ($reader->read) {
   if ( $reader->localName eq 'company' ) {
      print $reader->readInnerXml;
   };

}
```

notice after $reader->readInnerXml file pointer is still pointing to next node after company and while loop is reading the file twice.

is there anyway to point to next 'company' node after $reader->readInnerXml  and remove the while loop ?

thanks
Michael

Comment: The SAX parser is faster.

Comment: @alex, he'll have the same problem there, though.

Comment: Quick answer: 1) XML::Twig has a slower parser, but it will make this trivial. 2) If you're going to continue using a pull parser like XML::LibXML::Reader or a SAX parser, you will need to keep track of which nodes are open (using a stack) in order to find the end of the appropriate element.

Comment: @alex, we still cat't parse a 15G file with any parser. my hope is to break it down to smaller chunks and validate it and doing additional checks.

Comment: @michael The SAX should not keeping any data inside unless you have very very deep recursion. I think the SAX is the only hope for 15 G XML. I remember DOM parser killed Linux server by parsing 1 G XML. (The ulimit was set for unlimited memory use). Check for your script and stream everything to the disk. Don't keep XML trees in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If nodes that you need are on the same level then you can try the following:

```
my $pattern = XML::LibXML::Pattern->new('/*/company');
$reader->nextPatternMatch($pattern)
  or die "E: pattern not found.\n";

do {
    print $reader->readOuterXml();
} while ( $reader->nextSiblingElement() );
```